# Leer números de un archivo de texto y guardarlos en una variable (o lista) para graficarlos con MatPlotLib | Python

Tags: python, string, lista, archivo

Programé un método de bisección el cual me dará varias iteraciones y varias soluciones hasta llegar a la "raíz".
Esos resultados los guardé en un archivo de texto con mi programa de Python, y luego necesito leer ese archivo y guardar los datos del archivo en una variable de mi programa, pero esta variable sería tipo un vector, ya que necesito que con X (número de iteraciones) e Y (valor de las iteraciones) se me forme una gráfica.
Pero al querer leer los números del archivo y guardarlos en una variable, estos se guardan como tipo String, además de que aparecen todos en una sola línea. **Lo que me gustaría es que estos números del archivo de texto, se guardasen en mi programa en un vector o una lista, para poder graficarlos.**

Aquí estoy creando el archivo y guardando los valores que me da mi programa de Bisección. *(La función se ejecuta cada vez que se encuentra una iteración nueva dentro del programa, y así va añadiendo los números).*

```
def crearArchivo(resultado):
  archivo=open("biseccion.txt","a")
  resultado=str(resultado)
  archivo.write(" "+resultado)
  archivo.close()

def crearArchivo2(cont):
  archivo2=open("iteraciones.txt","a")
  cont=str(cont)
  archivo2.write(" "+cont)
  archivo2.close()
```

Esas funciones me guardan los números de la siguiente forma:

[image: Impresión de función CrearArchivo y CrearArchivo2]

Y ahora acá tengo otra función para leer el archivo, sacar sus números y guardarlos en una variable y graficarlos.

```
def leerGraficar():
  archivo3=open("biseccion.txt","r")
  guardado_biseccion=archivo3.read()
  archivo3.close()
  archivo4=open("iteraciones.txt","r")
  guardado_iteraciones=archivo4.read()
  archivo4.close()
```

Sin embargo, la función guarda los números como String en una línea de texto y yo quiero que cada uno (Bisección -> Y, Iteraciones -> X) se guarde en una lista (vector), quiero que esté de la siguiente forma, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia el read por readlines y haces `[float(n) for n in readlines().split(" ")]`

Comment: Cómo y en qué parte del código implementaría esa línea?
Sería después de guardar los datos en la variable?

Comment: simplemente lo colocas después de haber abierto el archivo y no te olvides de almacenar el resultado en una variable

Comment: Lo coloco de la siguiente forma: guardado_biseccion=[float(n) for n in readlines().split(" ")] | Sin embargo, me dice que readlines no está definido, qué valores debe llevar readlines? porque se supone es un comando

Comment: perdón que se me ha pasado, debe de ser `archivo4.readlines()`

Comment: Listo, ahora sí me dejó hacerlo, pero me saltó el siguiente error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split', no entiendo por qué no me deja, si es literalmente un solo string con espacios.

Comment: Me he equivocado nuevamente, debes hacer `[float(n) for n in archivo4.readlines()[0].split(" ")]`

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que tienes expresiones de Python (listas en tu caso) en formato string y necesitas evaluarlas. Esto se puede hacer con el modulo de la STL de Python `ast`.

Pongamos que tenemos la siguiente lista en formato string: `guardado_biseccion = "[1,2,3,4,5]"`

Si queremos convertirlo a una lista,hacemos lo siguiente.

```
import ast

guardado_biseccion = "[1,2,3,4,5]"

biseccion_lista = ast.literal_eval(guardado_biseccion)
```

El contenido de `biseccion_lista` ahora será una lista en vez de un string.

`literal_eval()` es una función que evalua una expresión nodo o string. Es decir si le pasamos una lista en formato string, lo convertirá en una lista, con una tupla, set, etc. Hará lo mismo.

### Bonus

La librería `ast` es utilizada por el propio lenguaje Python a la hora de parsear el código y transformarlo a `C` para que pueda ser ejecutado.

Comment: Lo hago justo como menciona, sin embargo me aparece lo siguiente al ejecutarlo: https://prnt.sc/1sd2b37 ,dónde más está el problema?